# Can swift functions have a default completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, a function can have default values for a parameter like this:

```
func init(name: String = "foo"){...}
```

Can a function with a completion handler have a default value so that when calling a function there is no need to specify the completionHandler as nil, similar to the below?

```
func foo(completion: (success: Bool) -> void = nil){...}
```

Comment: Do you want the default to be nil, or do you want the default to be some particular completion handler?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can either do this:

```
func foo(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void = {_ in }) {
    completion(success:true)
}
```

Or this:

```
func foo(completion: ((success: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    completion?(success:true)
}
```

Comment: what about @escaping?